# Why is there such a long delay between scheduling and performing an activity function?

Tags: azure-durable-functions

I have an activity function which will:

- read a bunch of results from a process elsewhere in my pipeline, via azure blob storage
- perform some processing on each result, using the [fan-out, fan-in pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=csharp)
- Combine the original results with the newly processed data, and re-upload to blob storage

When I have a large number of results (~10,000) - I'm experiencing large delays between finishing my processing, and the upload activity actually triggering.

I'm seeing the processing take ~3-4 minutes, then my "PersistResults" activity is scheduled - then 10 minutes later, the "PersistResults" activity actually runs, and takes about 20 seconds to run.

My guess is that the large payload on the "Persist" activity function is slowing it down a lot - though I've read nothing about limiting that, and the documentation certainly implies that any actual work I do (e.g. storing results) should be done in the activities to keep the orchestrator deterministic.

Actually uploading the results to storage appears to be fairly quick, given that when my activity does run, it only takes 20 seconds.

The final payload (all combined results) is roughly 50MB uncompressed - I notice that within the durable functions storage account it uses a compressed version for the activity input.

- Is this significant delay expected when using durable functions like this?
- Is there anything I've likely done to cause such a delay?
- Is there anything I can do to prevent it?